# Gutenberg block don't save rich text content

Tags: php, functions, javascript, block-editor

I could not get to work. When published the content the attribute innerContent didn't save. Here is what I tried.

**block.js**

```
//  Import CSS.
import './style.scss';
import './editor.scss';

const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { RichText } = wp.editor;

registerBlockType( 'hall/block-server-side-render', {
    title: __( 'Server Side Rendering' ),
    icon: 'shield',
    category: 'common',
        keywords: [
        __( 'Server Side Rendering' )
    ],
    attributes: {
      innerContent: {
          type: 'array',
              source: 'children',
              selector: 'p'
      }
    },
   edit: function( props ) {
       function onChangeContent( content ) {
            props.setAttributes( { innerContent: content } );
        }

    return (
        <div className={ props.className }>
                   <div class="gray-bg">
                      <RichText tagName="p" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" value={props.attributes.innerContent} onChange={onChangeContent} />
                   </div>
        </div>
        );
    },
    save: function( props ) {
        return null;
    },
} );
```

**init.php**

```
register_block_type( 'hall/block-server-side-render', array(
    'render_callback' => 'hall_render_inner_content',
    'attributes' => array(
        'innerContent' => array(
            'type' => 'array'
        )
    )
));

function hall_render_inner_content( $attributes ) {
    $innerContent = $attributes['innerContent'];
    return '<div class="inner-content">' . $innerContent . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: You made a typo here (in `onChangeContent()`): `props.attributes(` - and that should be `props.setAttributes(`..

Comment: @SallyCJ, made the correction, edited the question, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:** When saving an attribute, always respect the *attribute **type***. So if your attribute is of the `array` type, then save the value as an array, e.g. `props.setAttributes( { innerContent: [ content ] } )`.

### Longer Answer

1. Your [`register_block_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/) call is missing the `editor_script` parameter. See the block editor [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/#enqueuing-block-scripts) for details, but basically, you would need something like:

   ```php
   function hall_register_block() {
       wp_register_script(
           'hall-block-server-side-render',
           '/path/to/block.js',
           array( 'wp-i18n', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-block-editor' ),
           '1.0'
       );

       register_block_type( 'hall/block-server-side-render', array(
           'render_callback' => 'hall_render_inner_content',
           'attributes'      => array(
               'innerContent' => array(
                   'type'    => 'array',
                   // You should set a default value:
                   'default' => array(), // if the attribute is an array
   //              'default' => '',      // if the attribute is a string
               ),
           ),
           // Here, your code is missing the block's script:
           'editor_script'   => 'hall-block-server-side-render',
       ) );
   }
   add_action( 'init', 'hall_register_block' );
   ```
2. You defined the `innerContent` attribute as an array, so you would need to save it (via the `props.setAttributes()`) as an array:

   ```js
   function onChangeContent( content ) {
       // Save the value as an array.
       props.setAttributes( { innerContent: [ content ] } );
   }
   ```

   And omit the attribute's `source` and `selector` properties so that the attributes would be saved to (and read from) the block's [comment delimiter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/architecture/key-concepts/#delimiters-and-parsing-expression-grammar).

   ```js
   attributes: {
       innerContent: {
           type: 'array',
           // No need for these two:
   //      source: 'children',
   //      selector: 'p'
       }
   },
   ```

   But then, in your block render callback (`hall_render_inner_content()`), you would also need to parse the HTML in the attribute value (which is *not* a simple array such as `[ 'HTML here', 'another HTML here', 'etc etc' ]`), and note that, in that callback, the `$content` is (or would supposedly be) an array and not a string.

   So you should probably just **change the attribute type to `string`**, i.e. just change the above `type: 'array',` to `type: 'string',`. And that way, you wouldn't need to save the attribute as an array.
3. You should import `RichText` from `wp.blockEditor` and *not* `wp.editor`:

   ```js
   const { RichText } = wp.blockEditor; // use this
   const { RichText } = wp.editor;      // not this
   ```

Comment: PS: Sorry, I meant `$innerContent` and not `$content`.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using string as attribute type, as in previous answer, and possibly set multiline attribute to true on Richtext and use multiline parameter in attributes, as explained here.
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#html

If you will be using multiline, be sure to set 'div.gray-bg' as selector in your case.

Comment: If the source is `html`, then the block's `save()` function would need to return an element, but I believe that's not the case with the block in question where the output is rendered on the server-side, hence the `save()` function should return `null`. But if we just want a `p` on pressing the "Enter" key, then we would set the [`multiline` property in `RichText`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/HEAD/packages/block-editor/src/components/rich-text/README.md#multiline-boolean--string) to `true`.

Comment: Yes, you are right if source is html and multiline is not set, Enter key creates `<br>` tag